# Conditional font-size based on font-family

Tags: jquery, html, css, conditional-statements, font-size

Is there any way to write conditional font-size based on font-family in CSS or jQuery?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question like giving an example what you want to achieve

Comment: @user1479606 I don’t know about you but I find the question utterly clear. No idea why it gets downvoted.

Comment: @KonradRudolph no it's not clear especially when you don't know about what is his current scenario and how can CSS achieve something like this?

Comment: @user1479606 Well, your first comment pretends to answer the question. Surely then you know what OP wants? Personally, I *don’t* know a way to do this (and in plain CSS it’s not possible). For reference, my understanding of the question is that the OP wants to automatically scale different fonts so that they match each other even though their native sizes (at 1em) differ.

Comment: pretty basic question really. Dont see anything unclear.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, that's your thought. I think differently which is let's say he has 3 different font-family type and depends on that 3 he will check if a paragraph has the specific font-size within that 3 and based on that make changes to the font-size dynamically. I'm not pretend to answer the question but I want to see some code snippet from OP and what have he tried.

Comment: @user1479606 As a beginner, I think there is a mistake in my question. I found the answers below and Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can easyly with jquery:

http://jsbin.com/acuzah/1/edit

```
if ($("div").css('font-family') === 'Arial')
{
  $("div").css({'color': '#00FF00'});
}
```

Using css() you read the property font-family, check if its Arial for example, then set whatever css property you want. Or add a class.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: It works only when the `font-family` property has been set literally to the value `Arial`. If this is enough, you could just as well (actually, better) set directly `font-size` as desired on those elements for which you set `font-family: Arial`.

Answer (score 5):

Not really. But in some limited and relatively useless sense, yes.

In CSS, properties are independent of each other, except when CSS specifications define a relationship.

In scripting, you can do many things, but the simple jQuery way, querying for `css('font-family')` only gives you the *specified* list. If you declare `font-family: Ariel, Helvetia, sansserif` (this declaration is intentionally broken, though formally valid), it will give you the string `Ariel, Helvetia, sansserif`, even though none of those fonts is actually used for the element. So this approach is useless for the most common use case (where you want to use a list of fonts, to cover different systems, and wish to make font size vary according to which font gets actually used).

There are tricky ways to try to find out, in JavaScript, the font actually use for an element. They are usually based on evaluating the width of some text and comparing the result with the width of that text in some fonts.

Finally, there is the logical, though poorly supported way of using [`font-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-size-adjust). Only Firefox supports it, and the support is partly broken in a serious way (it uses wrong x-height information; e.g., the [x-height of Verdana](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/x-height.html) is actually 0.545.

Comment: This is not an anwser at all. Also, jquery is the most logical choice here. if the font is not supported for some reason, and the real font turns out to be helvetica this will affect a very small portion of browsers. You seem to be new to css, but some browsers dont even support css or images. There is no way to make ANYTHING 100% compatible. Best way to solve this problem with the best cover for most browsers is jquery check set css.

Comment: @user1721135 In fact that answers the question very well. If in doubt, assume shortcomings in your own understanding rather than others’. Your assertion “you seem to be new to CSS” is downright laughable. Did *you* know about `font-size-adjust`? I don’t think so. Jukka did, and it’s exactly what OP is after (but it doesn’t work).

Comment: yes i know font-size-adjust and its useless since its not supported by many browsers. Mentioning a useless theoretical solution is what makes me question your expertise and real experiance. OP sound like he has to do a job and obey specifications, doesnt sound like hes working on a just-4-fun school project.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("div").css('font-family') === 'Arial')
{
  $("div").css({'font-size': '100px'});
}
```